# Making mistake in JSON

Tags: java, android, json, xml

I am facing problem

**Error**

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference

I am sure i am making mistake in fetching data from the J-SON Response

here what i am doing

```
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(incomingRecover_JSON);
        JSONArray dive = json.getJSONArray("items");

        for (int i=0 ; i< dive.length() ; i++) {

            JSONObject dive_deep = dive.getJSONObject(i);

            JSONObject dive_more_deep = dive_deep.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");


            String title = dive_more_deep.getString("title");
            String sub_title = dive_more_deep.getString("subtitle");


            Data_Holder store_things = new Data_Holder(title, sub_title);
            array_list.add(store_things);

        }
```

**and here is the J-SON **

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=global&maxResults=10&orderBy=newest

Comment: Check null for getting title and sub_title.

Comment: full exception stack show concrete lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all volumeInfo has title and subtitle.

getString() method returns null when there is no key.

Use try catch to handle null.

Answer (score 0):

Not all volumeInfo has title and subtitle.

getString() method returns null when there is no key.

So Either Use try catch to handle null or use has() meyhod to check whether key is present or not

Example :

```
if(dive_more_deep.has("subtitle))
{
 String sub_title = dive_more_deep.getString("subtitle");
}
```